# How do I center a rotated DIV as a corner banner?

Tags: css

I have a div which I'm using as a corner banner, but I'm having trouble centering the text after the DIV has been rotated 45 degrees. How do I calculate the top and left values so a DIV which is 300px wide is centered in the top left corner of the screen? Here is a snippet of my CSS and HTML:

```
#cornerBanner {
        color: #F47D31;
        background-color: #333;
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #888;
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        position: absolute; 
        width: 300px;
        top: 50px;
        left: -100px;
        text-align: center;
      }
```

`<DIV ID="cornerBanner">Beta</DIV>`

Answer (score 7):

It is centered. You just need to adjust the positioning of it slightly:

```
#cornerBanner {
        color: #F47D31;
        background-color: #333;
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #888;
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        position: absolute; 
        width: 300px;
        top: 45px;
        left: -95px;
        text-align: center;
      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/UxzaL/

Comment: how did you calculate the top and left values?

Comment: Just eyeball it bro - no need to over-complicate the little things ;)